# Export and import the ECMA6 class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How to export and use the `ECMA6` class? This is what I am doing now:

*parser.js*

```
module.exports = class Parser {
   static parse() {
   }

   static doNow() {
   }
}
```

Now in another file, I am doing:

```
var Parser = require('parser')
Parser.parse();
```

When `parse` is called on `Parser`, I get an error saying

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

with `Parser` highlighted.

What could be the reason for this? What is the correct to export and import the class?

Comment: A SyntaxError means the Javascript is malformed, rather than the value being incorrect. Can you show the actual calling code?

Comment: as you're asking about es6, check [here](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to call your module in an absolute way this is what causes problem.

I recommend using an IDE as webstorm or atom to not have this kind of problem in the future

try this :

```
var Parser = require('path/path/parser.js');
    Parser.parse();
```

for es6 is :

```
export default class Parser {
   static parse() {
   }

   static doNow() {
   }
}

import Parser from './path/path/parser';
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easier and more readable to do it like this:

```
class Parser {
   static parse() {
   }

   static doNow() {
   }
}

module.exports = Parser;
```

and in the requiring module:

```
const Parser = require('./path/to/module');
Parser.doNow();
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it seems the issue is the path of parser.

**File Structor**

-index.js

-parser.js

**index.js**

```
var Parser = require('./parser')
console.log('parser',Parser.parse());
```

**parser.js**

```
module.exports = class Parser {
   static parse() {
       return 'hello there'
   }

   static doNow() {
   }
}
```

**Terminal**

```
node index.js 
parser hello there
```